# How use rspec with with before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I cannot understand, how correct use before_validation callback with Rspec.

**models/category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
    validates_presence_of :name, :permalink
    before_validation :generate_permalink

    private
    def generate_permalink
        self.permalink = Russian.translit(name).parameterize if permalink.blank?
    end
end
```

**category_spec.rb**

```
describe Category do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }   
    it { should validate_presence_of(:permalink) }
    it "should generate permalink" do
        category = build(:category, name: "Category name", permalink: "")
        category.valid?
        category.permalink.should eq "category-name" 
    end
end
```

and **factories/categories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    name "Category name"
    permalink "category-name"
  end
end
```

For first two tests I got errors:

```
undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Ran into this too. The **`tl;dr`** answer is: you can't use `validate_presence_of` with an `before_validation` callback that sets the value of that attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check validation for an instance, not for the class itself:

```
it "should be invalid without a name" do
  category = build(:category, name: "some name", permalink: "some link")
  expect{ category.name = nil }.to change{ category.valid? }.to false
end
```

Validation of permalink presence in your code is excessive.
The `before_validation` callback will provide non-blank value for the permalink before validation. That's why validation of permalink will never fail.