# How to test before_validation callback model concerns in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda, rspec-expectations

I'm learning to write specs for my code and I'm still new to it. Trying to write specs / SharedExamples for my Model concerns, but I don't understand how to write it as I find this one very complicated.

If someone could help me or show me how to write spec for codes like these would be very helpful. Below is my concern AddStakeholder.

```rb
module AddStakeholder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_validation -> { add_stakeholders }
  end

  private

  def add_stakeholders
    return unless self.stakeholder

    company = if self.is_a?(Certificate)
                self.round ? self.round.company : self.company
              else
                self.company
              end
    existing_stakeholder = company.stakeholders.find_by_email(self.stakeholder.email)
    if existing_stakeholder.present?
      if self.stakeholder.name == existing_stakeholder.name
        self.stakeholder = existing_stakeholder
      else
        self.stakeholder.company = company
      end
    else
      self.stakeholder.company = company
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use rspec with with before\_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358574/how-use-rspec-with-with-before-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information in your code snippet to prepare a full example but it would look somewhat along the lines of:

```
RSpec.describe Thing, type: :model do
  it "adds stakeholders" do
    t = Thing.new(...)
    expect(t).to be_valid # or .to_not be_valid depending on your validations on Thing
    expect(t.stakeholder).to ... # whatever you expect it to be
  end
end
```

Comment: The above code snippet is of a concern. I believe yours is a spec for a model. Do you think this can be used for concerns as well?

Comment: You could use it to test the Thing extended with the concern, at the same time you could follow this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525222/how-to-test-a-concern-in-rails